# Make maximum 1's by flipping k bits at a time

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, bit, bitstring

Given an n-bit vector and an integer k, 1 <= k <= n, we have to maximize the number of ones in it by applying the following operation any number of times(including zero):

- Choose exactly k bits(not necessarily continuous) and flip their state (0 to 1, 1 to 0);

After some analysis, I have come to the conclusion if n > k,  we can also flip any two bits simultaneously. For example for n = 5, k = 4. We can do something like this to flip last two bits only.

- xxxx_
- xxx_x

'x' represents that we flip the bit at that position.

But I am not sure how to proceed after that and I am unable to make any more observations. So, what would be a correct approach? You may assume an n^2 algorithm is feasible.

Comment: If *n-k* is small the naive O(n^k) approach could be fast enough,

Comment: @MrSmith42 Sadly, n - k isn't guaranteed to be small enough. Nonetheless, can you share the naive solution? I am unable to imagine any brute-force.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476533/n-bits-flip-exactly-m-bits-at-a-time-what-is-minimum-number-of-operations-to-g) should give you a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave's approach seems correct. I will share mine that I figured out after I posted the question here.

Let the number of zeroes be `z`, now convince yourself that if `k < n`, we can flip any two bits(a pair) by using a combination of the k-bit operation mentioned in the problem. Here's an argument to help you satisfy yourself with this fact, choose any `k - 1` bits other than the pair you want to flip; then choose one bit from the pair along with the `k - 1` we just picked, apply the operation; then choose the other bit from the pair along with the same `k - 1` bits we picked earlier, apply the operation again. We are guaranteed to find these `k - 1` auxiliary bits if `k < n` or `n` is at least `k + 1`.

So naturally, two cases arise:

- `k == n` : clearly we can only flip all or flip none. So the answer is `max(n - z, z)`
- `k < n` : In this case, we can flip any `k` bits or we can flip any 2 bits(using the argument above). Now, if `z < k`, we can only use the 2-bit flips and if `z` is odd, we are left with one bit still 0, answer is `n - 1`; if `z` is even, we flip all of them to 1's, so answer is `n`. Now when `z >= k`, we can use both k-bit fips and 2-bit flips, the claim is, if `z` is odd and `k` is even, we are left with one 0(answer is `n - 1`) otherwise we can always turn all 0's to 1's(answer is `n`).

**Explanation of the last claim:** If we can use both k-bit flips and 2-bit flips and `z` happens to be odd, we try to use one k-bit flip to change the parity of remaining 0's(parity of `z - k`). We can only do so if k is odd otherwise we can't do it and using 2-bit operations on odd number of zeroes will leave us with one zero. So, in a nutshell, if `k` is even with odd `z`, we will be left with one 0, otherwise we get all 1's.

Answer (score 2):

Flip zeroes until the number of zeroes is below k. Let m be the number of zeroes.

Flip k - m/2 ones and m/2 zeroes (integer division). Now you have m + (k-m/2) - m/2 = m + k - m/2 - m/2 ~ k zeroes. (approximate b/c of the integer division).

Finally, flip all the zeroes and as many ones as necessary to get k total flips. This will be either all ones or close depending on the parity of m.